# CrashPlan desktop app suddenly terminated after Splash Screen

Tags: java, gui, jdk, crashplan

### CrashPlan desktop app suddenly terminated after Splash Screen

- This was a fresh CrashPlan install on Ubuntu 14.04 amd64 with Oracle Java 7 JDK.
- Most of `/usr/local/crashplan/log/....log` was not contained relevant
  error messages, but I found a nice one in `/usr/local/crashplan/log/ui_output.log`:

```
#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  SIGSEGV (0xb) at pc=0x00007f313f4702a1, pid=25099, tid=139851489089280
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_67-b01) (build 1.7.0_67-b01)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.65-b04 mixed mode linux-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  [libsoup-2.4.so.1+0x6c2a1]  soup_session_feature_detach+0x11
#
# Failed to write core dump. Core dumps have been disabled. To enable core dumping, try "ulimit -c unlimited" before starting Java again
#
# An error report file with more information is saved as:
# /tmp/hs_err_pid25099.log
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#
```

FYI: I caould attach from my Windows CrashPlan Client to this Ubuntu daemon, so the daemon was good.

Answer (score 8):

I have found a working solution (workaround) in an Eclipse related StackOverflow article: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20203771/eclipse-continue-crash

And *@Erigami* have found a CrashPlan article:
https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/CrashPlan_App_Closes_In_Some_Linux_Installations

### Solution/Workaround

Have to add `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` JVM parameter to startup config of CrashPlanDesktop.

1. Open `/usr/local/crashplan/bin/run.conf` with `sudo`
2. Append `-Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla` to end of `GUI_JAVA_OPTS` variable.
3. Save the file. It have to looks like this:

   ```
   SRV_JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPlanService -DappBaseName=CrashPlan -Xms20m -Xmx1024m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=300 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=300 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=0 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=0 -Dc42.native.md5.enabled=false"
   GUI_JAVA_OPTS="-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -Dapp=CrashPlanDesktop -DappBaseName=CrashPlan -Xms20m -Xmx512m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Dsun.net.inetaddr.ttl=300 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.ttl=300 -Dsun.net.inetaddr.negative.ttl=0 -Dnetworkaddress.cache.negative.ttl=0 -Dc42.native.md5.enabled=false -Dorg.eclipse.swt.browser.DefaultType=mozilla"
   ```
4. It works! Cheers! ;)

### ​​Note

If you reinstall the app, the app automatically upgrades itself, then the `run.conf` file will be overwritten!

Comment: This is also documented in https://support.code42.com/CrashPlan/Latest/Troubleshooting/CrashPlan_App_Closes_In_Some_Linux_Installations

Comment: @Erigami: Thank you for this info, I updated the answer.

Comment: This didn't work for me...

Comment: @fccoelho: Can tell any info about your system for we can solve this problem?